# Custom eqv?/equal? function in scheme

Tags: function, comparison, scheme

How would I go about writing my own eqv? or equal? in scheme? Would I just do a cond and look for symbol?, number?, etc and return the appropriate #t or #f?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/), the minimum specifications for an implementation of `eqv?` (when passed two arguments `obj1` and `obj2`) to evaluate to `#t`are:

- `obj1` and `obj2` are both `#t` or both `#f`. (how two boolean literals evaluate to the same value is implementation dependent).
- `obj1` and `obj2` are both symbols and

`(string=? 
   (symbol->string obj1) 
   (symbol->string obj2)) =) 
=> #t`

- `obj1` and `obj2` are both numbers, are numerically equal (`=`), and are either both exact or both inexact.
- `obj1` and `obj2` are both characters and are the same character according to the `char=?` procedure.
- both `obj1` and `obj2` are the empty list.
- `obj1` and `obj2` are pairs, vectors, or strings that denote the same locations in the store (See section 3.4 of R5RS).
- `obj1` and `obj2` are procedures whose location tags are equal (A `lambda`
  expression is *conceptually* tagged with a storage location. What that means varies between Scheme implementations. Also see section 4.1.4 of R5RS).

`equal?` could be implemented in terms of `eqv?` as it recursively compares the contents of pairs, vectors, and strings, applying `eqv?` on other objects such as numbers and symbols.